# DRF ManyToMany field seralize

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contacts')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

When the user log-in, the client make a HTTP request to the following view to get user friends.

```
class ContactAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
```

The data returned:

[image]

THE QUESTION IS:

How can I serializer the 'friends' field in a way that I can get the `id`, `user.id` and `user.username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')
    username = ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'username']
```

and

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friends = FriendSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...
```

Comment: What is this `model = Track`

Comment: @Dosbodoke fixed